# Problem with characters in MySQL -> Php -> HTML

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have some text in a data table that contains this character: "•"

When I look at the text from phpMyAdmin, it looks OK, which means the right character is in the data, but if I query it with PHP and `echo` it, even if I use `htmlentities`, it will look like a weird square in IE and like � in Chrome.

I have the same problem with this two characters: “ and ”

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I just tried utf8_encode and at least the ugly chars disappear, but this is still not what I want. My page's char encoding is utf8, same as phpMyAdmin's page encoding. There must be a way to show it right because phpMyAdmin does it

Comment: And it comes out right in FF? Or any other browser? I can save it to a php variable and echo it. Viewing in Chrome - worked.

Comment: I get the question mark on FF

Comment: Oh now I see what you are saying. OK I tried the same and it also worked. So now I'm more confused.

Comment: I really think the problem is with MySQL, because I can properly echo the character if I do this: `echo "•";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's encoding issue,  your page encoding might be different from the database encoding .  either set both database and page to same encoding or use a function for example utf8_encode($variable) or utf8_decode

**Edit:**
try add AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 in the htaccess

Comment: I just tried utf8_encode and at least the ugly chars disappear, but is still not what I want. My page's char encoding is utf8, same as phpMyAdmin. There must be a way to show it right because phpMyAdmin does it.

Comment: Are you sure is your page utf8?,  go to browser then check encoding see what is selected on your page. sometimes settings of the server make it ignore what you set for encoding in the html.  beside what's the encoding of the database and the table and the field. make sure they are all utf8.

Comment: OK I just saw in Fiddler. My page is "Content-Type: text/html", but phpMyAdmin is "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8". Wonder if that's the problem. Can you change this from PHP code?

Comment: How about you try add AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 in the htaccess? and see if it works for you.

Comment: @jsoldi: Try adding `<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">` to your `<head></head>` section of your page

Comment: I already have that meta. Also I tried setting a header with PHP like this: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and still having the same problem.

Comment: did you try adding the htaccess one?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this query after connecting to the database:

`mysqli_query($this->conn, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');`

`$this->conn` is your connection to the database.

further information on `SET NAMES 'utf8'` can be obtained from [MySQL Reference Manual Chapter 9.1.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: Should I do that before or after `mysql_select_db`?

Comment: I am doing it after db selection.

Comment: I think your code is for MySQL lite or something. I tried `mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');` but it looks even messier.

Comment: `mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'")`

Comment: In Firefox open Page Information (right click in Page -> Page Information) and add a screenshot of the appearing window to your question. My database is our production database, a fully grown up-to-date MySQL

Answer (score 0):

What is encoding of a data in MySQL? Php doesn't support raw unicode yet.